# Is R's glm function useless in a big data / machine learning setting?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, glmnet, separation

I am surprised that R’s `glm` will “break” (not converge with default setting) for the following “toy” example (binary classification with ~50k data, ~10 features), but `glmnet` returns results in seconds.

Am I using `glm` incorrectly (for example, should I set max iteration, etc.), or is R’s `glm` not good for big data setting? Does adding regularization make a problem easy to solve?

```
d=ggplot2::diamonds
d$price_c=d$price>2500
d=d[,!names(d) %in% c("price")]

lg_glm_fit=glm(price_c~.,data=d,family = binomial())

library(glmnet)
x=model.matrix(price_c~.,d)
y=d$price_c
lg_glmnet_fit=glmnet(x = x,y=y,family="binomial", alpha=0)

Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

EDIT:
Thanks for Matthew Drury and Jake Westfall's answer. I understand the perfect separation issue which is which is already addressed.  [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression)

And in my original code, I do have the third line which drops the column that derives the label.

The reason I mention about "big data" is because in many "big data" / "machine learning" settings, people may not carefully test assumptions or know if data can be perfectly separated. But `glm` seems to be easily broken with "unfriendly" messages, and there is not a easy way to add the regularization to fix it.

Comment: In general R won't work in big data setting since it loads all your data into RAM, so for terabytes of data you would need even more terabytes of RAM...

Comment: Regarding " Does adding regularization make a problem easy to solve":  yes, it can.  See http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf: "Inclusion of $\lambda$ makes problem non-singular even if $Z^T Z$ is not invertible"

Comment: ...and your perfect separation / non-invertibility issue doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the size of your training data (i.e. whether you're dealing with "big data" or not)

Comment: Personally, I think those messages are very friendly. If you have a 50,000 x 10 data set with perfect separation, and don't realize it, I don't think you've learned enough about your data.

Comment: `glm` doesn't fit regularized models because it's not designed to do so. Regularization will induce convexity and hence finite parameter estimates; however, it is not uniformly true that regularization is the correct answer in all contexts. Even if convex models are desired, they can be constructed from alternative, non-regularized models, so it's a matter of choosing the correct tool for the task at hand. Please see Scortchi's answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression

Comment: @CliffAB: in order to be friendly, the messages would want to say *"fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred **for variable varA [,varB,...]**"*

Comment: @smci: unfortunately, that's not really a viable option. For a variety of reasons, it's not so easy to pinpoint the "responsible variable" in this problem, nor is the idea of a responsible variable even well defined. They **can** tell you that your estimated probabilities are numerically equal to 0 or 1, which should indicate that there are potential problems with your model.

Comment: This is an FAQ: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fitted+probabilities+numerically+0+or+1+occurred. But it can't be said often enough that nothing's "breaking": predicted probabilities of zero or one aren't inherently absurd, & it's only the Wald standard errors that'll be way out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The unregularized model is suffering from [complete](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224863/understanding-complete-separation-for-logistic-regression) [separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) because you are trying to predict the dichotomized variable `price_c` from the continuous variable `price` from which it is derived.

The regularized model avoids the problem of complete separation by imposing a penalty that keeps the coefficient for the `price` predictor from going off to $\infty$ or $-\infty$. So it manages to converge fine and work well.

You should remove the continuous `price` predictor from the design matrix in this toy example.

***Edit:*** As @Erik points out, the continuous `price` predictor *is* already removed from the design matrix, which I somehow missed. So the complete separation arises from some other predictor or combination of predictors.

It's also worth adding that, of course, none of these issues have anything to do with the particular implementation of logistic regression in R's `glm()` function. It is simply about regularized vs. unregularized logistic regression.

Answer (score 17):

This has nothing to do with `glm`, you simply created a problem with an artificial perfect separation:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df$y_c = df$y > 0

glm(y_c~., data=df, family=binomial())
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
>   2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

`y` is a perfect predictor of `y_c`.

Comment: While I think that perfect separation is still the basic issue, @hxd1011 excludes the price variable from d before fitting the model... see third line of code, though I am a bit unsure whether this works with operator precedence.

Comment: @Erik even without that variable, it's possible to have perfect separation.  Even `lg_glm_fit=glm(price_c ~ carat, data=d, family = binomial())` starts to run into problems

Comment: @Adrian Sure, that is why I said that the basic issue is correctly identified. However, note that this is not *artificial* perfect separation anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung up on Matthew's use of the word "artificial".  Perfect separation is the issue.  This isn't a problem with `glm` or with big data -- it's a problem with fitting an unregularized model when the solution is not unique (which can happen in big or small datasets).

Comment: @Adrian True, which is why I did not downvote. Still, my comment and yours right now would improve the answer if they got included.

Comment: I meant "artificial" in that the poster created it by leaving `y` in the regression, which should not be there.  Even if it did *not* fail so catastrophically, it would still be data leakage.

Comment: I must say @Erik, I unfortunately don't quite see your point on the price variable. But if you think it would be better to add some things to the answer, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @MatthewDrury y is taken out of the data (and the model) in the third line of the code.

Comment: Oh.  So it is.  Why is this getting so many upvotes?  I feel a fraud.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I think you posted your answer before `d=d[,!names(d) %in% c("price")]` was added (i.e. the original question was edited), right?  In any case, there's still a problem of perfect separation after that edit, but it's no longer "artificial"

Comment: @Adrian my original question has that line... but both answers fail to see that.