# Residual plot from a logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, residuals

Reposting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109921/residual-plot-from-a-logistic-regression)

I am implementing a two-stage logistic regression customer acquisition model and want to understand the peculiar pattern I observe in the residuals from the DHARMa R package.

The first stage model is a probit model

```
selection_model <- glm(I(acquired > 0) ~ m * b + l + w + f,
                       data = aggregate_df,
                       family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

Then I add in the inverse mills ratio like so:

```
aggregate_df$IMR = dnorm(selection_model$linear.predictors)/pnorm(selection_model$linear.predictors)
```

The second stage model shares the same predictors except that the inverse mills ratio is also added as a predictor. Also, I am interested in looking at those customers who have given a total sales of more than X. This is captured in a binary indicator variable `I(dollar_sales > X)`, which is the outcome I model in the second stage.

```
model_logit <- glm(I(dollar_sales > X) ~ IMR + m * b + l + w + f + 
                                         I(f^2) + I(l^2),
                   data = aggregate_df,
                   family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

I then plot the residuals of this model using the DHARMa package like so:

```
simulated_residuals = DHARMa::simulateResiduals(model_logit, n = 50)
plot(simulated_residuals)
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why are there two disjoint blobs at the bottom and top of the QQ plot? Is this a cause of concern (as the KS test indicates)?
2. The residual vs predicted plot seems okay, barring the outliers. Is this also expected behavior

[image: Residual plot from logistic regression]

Comment: You have some observations where your regressors perfectly predict if dollars_sales has a positive value. This is called perfect separation (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224863/understanding-complete-separation-for-logistic-regression).

Comment: Side note: I would advise against plugging your estimated IMR into the '2nd stage' regression. Doing it the way you do dismisses the variation caused by estimation error in selection_model which leads to invalid inference. Google 'generated regressor' for discussion on this.

Comment: @OttoKässi I read through the discussion on generated regressor. My sense is that the advice is to bootstrap the standard errors of the final estimates rather than relying on the output as is. There is no specific warning against addition of the estimates IMR but caution (like you suggest) on SE's. I will use the links to deal with the perfect separation issue (surprising that there is no warning that is issued by glm)