# Error message in logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, proportion

I am trying to understand how both temperature (factor: 6 levels - 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35 degrees Celsius) and species (factor: 2 levels HA and AP) affects the likelihood of moving from one life stage to the next (in this case from the 2nd instar to the 3rd) using a logistic regression model as below:

```
X3rdmodelA <- glm(cbind(No.3rd,No.2nd-No.3rd) ~ Temperature * Species, data=X2ndto3rd, weights = No.2nd, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

When I try to run the model the following error appears:

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

Would anyone be able to tell me why this error might be occurring and what I may do to fix it.

Below is the data I am using if this is helpful:

```
Temperature  Species  No.2nd  No.3rd
20           AP       32      30
23           AP       53      50
26           AP       46      39
29           AP       72      66
32           AP       38      32
35           AP        3       7
20           HA       41      41
23           HA       48      42
26           HA      117     113
29           HA       89      87
32           HA       42      42
35           HA       59      39
```

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's probably because of [tag:separation]. We have a number of threads about this, such as (1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254124 and (2) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224863 and (3) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803 and (4) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239928 What happens if you change the row `20 HA 41 41` to `20 HA 41 40`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've specified the model correctly

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("Temperature  Species  No.2nd  No.3rd
20           AP       32      30
23           AP       53      50
26           AP       46      39
29           AP       72      66
32           AP       38      32
35           AP        3       7
20           HA       41      41
23           HA       48      42
26           HA      117     113
29           HA       89      87
32           HA       42      42
35           HA       59      39")
dt[, Temperature := factor(Temperature)]
mdl <- glm(cbind(No.3rd, No.2nd) ~ Temperature * Species
           , data = dt
           , family = binomial)
```

works for me.

Note `?glm` says

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures.
>
> For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes

Comment: This explanation is plausible because the row `35 AP 3 7` suggests that OP has 7 successes and $3-7=-4$ failures, according to their code. I don't think this makes sense. Alteratnively, there could be a data entry error in that row (perhaps it's supposed to have 30 or 13 instead of 3), but the code is otherwise correct ("a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures").

Comment: @Sycorax My mistake the 7 should actually be a 1 so only 1 individual, out of three that reached the 2nd instar, then went on to reach the 3rd instar.

Comment: @Sycorax Unfortunately the error still occurs

Comment: @Ladybird_biologist I think the issue is [tag:separation]. The linked threads address this